# Pronunciation difference between "Mayonnaise" & "Vase"

Tags: pronunciation

I've seen quite many people pronounce "Mayonnaise" with "-s" at the end, although its phonetic alphabet is written as '/meɪəneɪz/'. So at first I thought /eɪ/ + s could be versatile as /eɪs/ or /eɪz/, before I noticed the word 'Vase', which I've never heard in my life anyone pronounce "veɪz"(/va-z/ maybe).
So I was wondering if there's any phonetic law or something with /eɪ/ sound, or is only mayonnaise ok either way because it's just a foreign word(French).

Comment: "Vase" is not a good example, because people pronounce that word in various ways (/veɪs/, /veɪz/, /vɑːz/). In general, you cannot exchange /eɪs/ and /eɪz/ in pronunciation. The word "face" is always pronounced /feɪs/, and the word "phrase" is always pronounced /freɪz/.

Comment: To a large degree, "mayonnaise" has multiple pronunciations because it doesn't matter -- the word is long enough and distinctive enough that a more precise pronunciation is unnecessary.  And "vase" is somewhat similar -- even though the word is not long, there are few other common words similar to it, so "vace", "vaze", and "vawze" are all heard.  "Face", however, is fairly well fixed, in part to avoid confusion with "phase".

Comment: Once I was in the Boston Metropolitan Museum and I overheard someone say "I don't know my Monets from my Manets, but I sure do love mayonnaise on my sandwich."

Comment: In Britain we pronounce *vase* to rhyme with *Mars* (or course Mars, with a non-rhotic r). *Mayonnaise*, pronounced the French way would end *...ez* But however it is pronounced it never rhymes with *vase* - not here anyway.